# OData in Datafactory

Tags: odata, azure-data-factory, azure-adf

I have a task toget some data from an external supplier.
They have a Rest OData API. I have to connect using a subscription-key(APIKey).
When creating the OData LService, I add an Auth Header: "subscription-key" and in the Value field, I enter my key. After saving, I create a new dataset, and the OData LinkedService, provides me with the remote tables. I can choose the table I want and after that I create a pipeline to copy data from that table to my Azure SQL server.

This works fantastic :-)
However, after closing my browser and re-open it, the subscription key that I have entered earlier on the linked service, is now replaced with stars as it is a securestring. When I now run my pipeline, it will think that my key is the ten stars that have replaced my real key.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Also I would prefer to get my value from the KeyVault, but it seems that this is not possible on ODat connections....

Hope someone is able to provide some insight here :-)

BR Tom

Answer (score 0):

From my testing I did not get any error on re-running. However coming to dynamic keys - I was not able to achieve it using the ODATA linked service.

Alternatively, if you can hit the ODATA endpoint with REST / HTTP Connector

You could - have a Web Activity to get the keys from the Key Vault and Set in the Variable.

[image]

**WEB Activity URL** : `https://<your-keyvalut-name>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<your-secret-name>`;

You could access the output of the web Activity using : `@activity('Web1').output.value & Store in a variable.`

You can reference this variable as the SUBSCRIPTION KEY for the subsequent steps in the REST/HTTP dataset.

You could pass it along the additional headers